# How to enter the file path in a windows pop-up in Robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I need to enter a filepath to upload a file in a windows pop-up, How to handle it in selenium+python+robot framework?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for file uploads, one does not open the OS dialog and enter the path there. If you did make it work somehow, then it would be specific for Windows; but what if the case is ran on Mac OS? Or headless Linux?

For this purpose in Selenium there's a special method, available in SeleniumLibrary as the [Choose File](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Choose%20File) keyword. Through it the full path is set as the value of the `input` element handling the upload, and no OS modal is brought up.
Selenium even has some special code to transfer the file, if the browser is a remote one (e.g. the file is local for the execution machine, but the browser is running on a different, remote one).

Comment: I tried using Choose File but it didn't accept because webelement is missing. This website is used only on a windows env, where we hav to manually scan and upload.

Comment: You have to be more specific than that - add to the original question what element did you target, and what's the surrounding html.

Comment: I wanted to add the filepath and click open, its a windows dialogue